# How to prevent core data issues in new versions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, app-store

> **I**  **forgot**
>    **to do core data migration**

before submitting new version of my app.When having installed Older version and update to new version , upon launch, the app crashes EVERY time.

When deleting new version and reinstalling the app, all works fine. We are talking prod versions on App Store.

Could you please tell me how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your you have to do lightweight migration :-

Make two Version of Datamodel [Safe]

Somthing like this:-

```
+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if ([DBHelper sharedCoreDataInstance].objPersistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return [DBHelper sharedCoreDataInstance].objPersistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationLibraryDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdb.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                              };

    [DBHelper sharedCoreDataInstance].objPersistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                                                       initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if(![[DBHelper sharedCoreDataInstance].objPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                                      configuration:nil
                                                                                                URL:storeURL
                                                                                            options:options
                                                                                              error:&error])
    {
        //Error for store creation should be handled in here
    }

    return [DBHelper sharedCoreDataInstance].objPersistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a version which does the data migration.

- Lets say users had the version 1.0
- Buggy version 1.1
- Now you release a good version 1.2.

If users update from 1.0 -> 1.2 it should work.
If users have already updated to 1.1 (did crash), the app could not change the data, so it should be ok if they updated from 1.1 -> 1.2 (But anyway try your self, if I am right)

Worst case:
I do not know what kind of data you have in core data, but if it is reconstructable, you can just delete the old data and create a new one.

Comment: I have only added a new attribute to one of the entities. But my question is : Is there anyway i can fix this without resubmitting the app?

Comment: Is there anyway i can fix this without resubmitting the app? :-/ :-|

Comment: No, you can't, you submitted a bad version, you have to submit a new version fixing the problem.

Comment: like jcesarmobile have told, unfortunately you have to submit a new version